# Elastic Beanstalk Django App REST API Fails with Multiple EC2 Instances

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm running a DJango App through and Elastic Beanstalk Environment that is setup to scale to multiple instance when the server load reaches a certain level.

The Django APP is being used as a REST API (DRF) and I have the django-cors-headers [https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers] app installed to handle requests from an Ionic Application. Requests are being made through Angular2's http framework, which makes pre-flight requests.

The application and requests work fine when there is only one instance running. However when Elastic Beanstalk starts up a second server because it has hit it's limits all of the requests start failing.  Requests that don't require authentication fail just the same as requests that do. If I make the request via Postman it works fine. So it has to be something to do with the CORS configuration.

The API is using the https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-api-key framework to provide a API Key so this is also part of the setup.

I've been looking through the web and have tried virtually everything I could find. I tried setting the Headers manually in the apache configuration through ebextensions. I looked into ngnix settings, but wasn't sure what could be done there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. It had nothing to do with CORS at all. The problem revolved around the Elastic Load Balancer health status. The health status was immediately returning as good before the Django application was successfully installed and spun up. Therefore my requests were trying to hit a service that wasn't even running. To resolve this issue I created a custom health check for the ELB.

- Create a Django View called health and just have it return a 200. You can make the url path be whatever you want. Mine is just /health
- Within your ELB configure the health check to use HTTP on PORT 80 and set the ping path to the url of your health page. (/health)
- Done.